# Center map in Google Maps during start-up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Need to center map on load to value set in string in location array.  When I try to run this, it renames the html file in browser with "London,New%20York".  Google Maps API works otherwise.

Am I missing some funda here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map;
            var location = ["London", "New York"];
            var pos;

            function initialize()
            {
                google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                getGeoCode();
                var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: pos,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
             }

            function getGeoCode()
            {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': location[1]}, function(results, status){
                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    pos = results[0].geometry.location;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Not found");
                }
              });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it has anything to do with the code you have posted.  The code you have posted won't do anything useful, but it won't cause the behavior you are reporting.  The geocoder is asynchronous, you need to use the results ("pos") inside the callback routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "location" is a [reserved word in javascript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

when you set that to

```
var location = ["London", "New York"];
```

You change the url of the page.

You also have a problem with the asynchronous behavior of the geocoder, you need to use the results in the callback function.  This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map;
            var locations = ["London", "New York"];
            var pos;

            function initialize()
            {
                google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                getGeoCode();
             }

            function getGeoCode()
            {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': locations[1]}, function(results, status){
                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    pos = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var mapOptions = {
                      zoom: 8,
                      center: pos,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Not found");
                }
              });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
```

Comment: On that thought, it's true if `var location` is declared in the global scope - but should be fine if you wrap your code in an IIFE. And if at all you need to refer to your global `location` object just call `window.location`.

Comment: @geocodezip What is the best way to code using Maps JavaScript API v3?

Comment: That is a complete course on software engineering (and not appropriate for StackOverflow comments...), but most people learn "on the job" (or on the web).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
I had same issue.but in bing map.
First you have to hard code the latitude and longitude for  initial location.

```
var startingLat = 43.0729484;  // view of Madison
var startingLng = -89.3866882;  // view of Madison
var startingZoom = 15;

var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(startingLat, startingLng)
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
```

Hope you get an idea.

edit:

```
//first declare   
  var viewBoundaries;
      //(this will work for bing maps)
    viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(your locationAry);
      map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries });
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code it.  I actually want to randomize location in location array[] at start-up.

Why the hell is it renaming my source file?  I think this is more of a JavaScript issue?

Comment: first declare var viewBoundaries;
   then assign 
viewBoundaries = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(your locationAry);(for bing maps)
  map.setView({ bounds: viewBoundaries });

Answer (score 0):

replace your both function

```
function initialize()
     {
          google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 10,

           };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
          getGeoCode();
     }

     function getGeoCode()
        {
                        geocoder.geocode({'address': location[1]}, function(results, status){
                        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        {
                            pos = results[0].geometry.location;
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Not found");
                        }
                      });
        }
```

hope this help